# why would a userscript wrapped in a firefox addon be slower than the same script in greasemonkey?

Tags: firefox-addon, greasemonkey, firefox-addon-sdk, userscripts

I've been working on converting a Greasemonkey userscript into a Firefox addon.  I'm using the page-mod module and it appears to work as expected.

EXCEPT that it is noticeably slower!

The first action that is slower is the load of the script.  Even though I've set my `contentScriptWhen` to `ready`, the xpi version (which, among other things inserts a checkbox for toggling its actions) takes much longer to load and show its checkbox.

The second action that is slower is its toggle action.  The affect of the toggle takes noticeably longer to execute.

The script is long and involved so I haven't included it here.  But in general, it uses jQuery (pasted into the referenced `contentScriptFile`) to make a number of modifications to the page.  Those mods are turned on and off by the aforementioned toggle.

Can anyone think of general reasons why the same userscript, when loaded via an XPI addon, would be considerably and noticeably slower than that same script is when loaded via Greasemonkey?

Comment: The new SDK creates add-ons with a fair amount of overhead.  I don't remember if Greasemonkey now caches information (IIRC Scriptish does), but your add-on for sure doesn't unless you've built that in.  ... The way you are using jQuery may be a big slowdown.  (1) Set `When` to start, (2), just include jQuery, don't paste it in, eg: `contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-1.7.2.min.js"), data.url("my-content-script.js")]`, and (3) then use a standard `$(document).ready(...` in `my-content-script.js`. Also, make sure you're not running in iframes unless you want to.

Comment: This should have been the answer, and I'm really curious to know if these measures help at all. Another option: use zepto instead of jQuery as it is much smaller, yet functionally ( roughly ) the same.

Comment: @BrockAdams thanks so much for the suggestions. i tried them all, but unfortunately the primary slowness remains. it did speed up the insertion of elements into the page, but the toggle action I mentioned above is still slow. if you have any other ideas, let me know. thx! (oh, and i'm not running in iframes)

Comment: Is the toggle action slower than the Greasemonkey script?  Seems doubtful. ...  Probably can't do much more to help you without a code review (which is not what SO is for), or unless you can boil the problem down to a small, self-contained example.

Comment: definitely, the toggle action is slower. i know it doesn't make sense. you may recall another recent SO question of mine about using console.time() on FF addons...couldn't get it to work so I haven't quantified the disparity. i tried to boil it down to a workable example but haven't come up with something yet. if I do i'll post it as a question. thx

Answer (score -1):

Page-mods are UserScripts are implemented differently, the former is more all proxified and more secure, but also slower in some cases.  The better written your page-mod is the more it will benefit.